# Using Multiple Emulators for the same Project

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I am trying to use multiple emulators for the same project and running into difficulty. I am a total beginner to Android. Is it possible to use an avd emulator for part of a project i.e. multiple activites and to then switch to a google maps emulator to show a map bases on some user input? Im aware that I could just use the google maps emulator and design using map overlays but is there a way to use two emulators at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Depend on Your Project `Android SDK Version` or `API Level` 
If you Use Google Map then Use `Google-API`, If your App have Map then You must have `Google-API` emulator,And if your APP have not map You can also Use this Emulator.As per Your `API LEVEL` Emulators using 'Google-API' That works in ALL same level API....

Comment: I have a map example completed from an online tutorial, this project uses the Google-API emulator. The API level I use is level 15 and the platform is 4.0.3  I am wondering can I also use this emulator for non-map activites i.e a HelloWorld activity?

Comment: Oh ok Great! i was under the impression that a Google-API emulator could only be used for google-map activites, overlays etc. So I can use this google-map emulator for everything in my project, including Database, menus, maps and multiple activites? Also I can remove the other avd i was using?

Comment: yup You can do all ...But what" I can remove the other avd i was using?"

Comment: thats fantastic, thank you so much Samir!!! Oh its a simple avd I set up with the target of Android 4.0.3 instead of Google APIs.